# Make an Image as a backgound in java android for edit

Tags: java, android, image, edit

I had created an image by the following code:

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(512, 512, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);

try {
    int tile1ResID = getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/m" + String.valueOf(tileOfPoint.x) + "_" + String.valueOf(tileOfPoint.y), "drawable", "com.example.sabtt1");

    canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), tile1ResID), 256, 256, true), 0, 0, null);
    canvas.save();
}
catch (Exception e) {
}

canvas.save();

ImageView imgMap1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgMap1);
imgMap1.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, 500, 500)));
```

now I want to make it as background. So that the user can add an image or draw on it. 
How can I set it as background?
Is it possible to add the image and draw by finger at the same time?

I use this code for draw:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    try {
        Bitmap gestureImg = gesture.getGesture().toBitmap(100, 100, 8, Color.BLACK);

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        gestureImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
        byte[] bArray = bos.toByteArray();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);

        intent.putExtra("draw", bArray);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(Activity1.this, "No draw on the string", 3000).show();
    }
}
```

and OnDragListener for add and move images.

I know that I should use the folowing code for background:

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.nn);
    this.setContentView(ll);
```

but by using this code, I can't see other images.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can just draw on the main bitmap the other bitmaps:

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(512, 512, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
bmp = <load from resource>
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
Bitmap gestureImg = <get bitmap from gesture or loading>
canvas.drawBitmap(gestureImg);
```

then load the final bitmap:

```
ImageView imgMap1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgMap1);
imgMap1.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, 500, 500)));
```

Or you can store the main bitmap and all other gesture/loaded bitmaps in separate objects and when you want to update the `imgMap1` you make your combined bitmap;

Also to use as background the new bitmap use:

```
ll.setBackgroundDrawable( new BitmapDrawable( bmp ) );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But I should create an image, and that is part of a map. 
based on that image, user is able to add more images and draw. 
so, I can't make them all together or at the same time. after creating the first one, I should let user to add more images. 
do u have any idea for that?

Comment: Basically you could hold all the images in an ArrayList (but it is expensive in terms of memory) and every time user finishes to add an image you draw all the images from the ArrayList to the main (Map) and show him the result.

Comment: yes as you said, ArrayList is expensive. furthermore, I am creating the first Bitmap in one activity and the second one in another activity. 
so it should be ready in another page.